# JUnit testing of spring/jsf controller - data reset

Tags: java, spring, jsf, junit, primefaces

I encountered the following problem. I have a controller with model which contains some fields, lists etc. Now I have a `@Before` method where I initialize some test data. Unfortunately with every call such as `model.getList().add(element)` this list has new reference and is created again and my data is lost. I can debug into `add` method and check that it adds it properly, then when next `add` is called, the list has new reference and is empty. Due to that problem, when it comes to `@Test` methods, they should call some controller method and do operation on previously added data, but there are none. Scope of my controller and model is `@Scope(value = "view", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`. When I change it to `@SessionScope` then it works fine, but I had to switch the scope to `view` because of application requirements. Can you help me with solving this problem? Maybe other way of testing or any other ideas?

Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = "view", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class BaseController extends AbstractController<BaseModel> {
    //some logic 
}
```

part of AbstractController:

```
@Autowired
protected T model;

@Override
public T getModel() {
    return model;
}
```

model class:

```
@Repository
@Scope(value = "view", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class BaseModel extends AbstractModel {

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      //initialization stuff
  }

//data logic methods

}
```

And finally my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
public class BaseControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private BaseController controller;

@Autowired
private BaseModel model;

@Autowired
private LoggingDao loggingDao;

private MockMvc mvc;

private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO1;
private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO2;
private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO3;
private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO4;
private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO5;
private UsbDeviceDBO usbDeviceDBO6;

@Before
public void before() {
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();

    FacesContext context = ContextMocker.mockFacesContext();
    UIViewRoot uiViewRoot = Mockito.mock(UIViewRoot.class);
    Mockito.when(context.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot())
            .thenReturn(uiViewRoot);
    Mockito.when(
            context.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale())
            .thenReturn(new Locale("en"));
}

public void insertTestData() {
    usbDeviceDBO1 = new UsbDeviceDBO("device1", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "Custom", "comment1");
    usbDeviceDBO2 = new UsbDeviceDBO("device2", EDeviceUsageMode.INSTALL, "Custom", "comment2");
    usbDeviceDBO3 = new UsbDeviceDBO("device3", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "Custom", "comment3");
    usbDeviceDBO4 = new UsbDeviceDBO("USB\\class_01", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "Class 01: Audio", "comment4");
    usbDeviceDBO5 = new UsbDeviceDBO("USB\\VID_05BA&PID_000A", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "[Diebold] (Digital Persona, Inc) Biometric Reader", "comment5");
    usbDeviceDBO6 = new UsbDeviceDBO("USB\\VID_0596&PID_0001", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "[Wincor Nixdorf] 3M Touch Controller", "comment5");

    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO1);
    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO2);
    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO3);
    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO4);
    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO5);
    model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO6);

    model.getUsbDeviceTable().clearSelection();
}

@Test
public void updateUsedDeviceIdsTest() {
    insertTestData();
    UsbDeviceDBO clonedDevice = new UsbDeviceDBO("device1", EDeviceUsageMode.ALWAYS, "Custom", "comment1");
    controller.updateUsedDeviceIds(clonedDevice);

    assertEquals(5, model.getUsedDeviceIds().size());
}
```

And everytime when it comes to `updateUsedDeviceIdsTest` method, assertion fails yet there should be 5 elements, but when test data is added, after every call of `model.getUsbDeviceTable().add(usbDeviceDBO1);` I get new reference to the list with data. And due to that when my `controller.updateUsedDeviceIds(clonedDevice);` start, the list has 0 elements.  The same happens to regular objects, not collections, in my model. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using SpringBoot 2.0.2 + PrimeFaces 6.2, running on IntelliJ IDE, JSF version 3.2.1, JUnit 4.12

Comment: What is the `clearSelection()` method doing?

Comment: `table.getSelectedList().clear()` - it just clears current selection of table, different list that data is being added to.

Comment: there's no scope such as view on spring. Are you using a listener or something like this https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes?